# How to mark a property not accessible in predicates

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using a property in my model which is not mapped to database fields.
But it's accessible in predicates :

```
Queryable().Where(w => w.MyProperty == "HELLO")

[NotMapped]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

How can I forbid the access of this property in predicates?

Comment: Son any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is the best solution, but if you want to keep these properties as part of your model you can move model classes to a separate project and mark all the properties which you want to hide as `internal`, in that way these properties can be only be accessed within that assembly unless you specify

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo()]
```

Comment: I can not access anymore to the property. I only need to exclude the property from queryable

Answer (score 0):

You need to transition to in-memory query execution using .AsEnumerable(), .ToList(), etc:

EG

```
var q = db.SomeEntity.Where( e => e.SomeMappedProperty == "A");

var results = q.AsEnumerable().Where(w => w.MyProperty == "HELLO");
```